# How to use the same layout in a different directory?

Tags: hugo, hugo-content-organization

I have a site using the [`hugo-coder`](https://github.com/luizdepra/hugo-coder) theme, which has a `layouts/posts` folder that specifies that anything in the "posts" folder will have a blog post format.

I would like to have two different blogs in two different subdirectories, using the same layout. Is there a way to tell Hugo that the `content/blog1` directory should use the same settings and layout as the `content/posts` directory without copying `themes/hugo-coder/layouts/posts` into `layouts/blog1`? Ideally I would avoid using symlinks, because, while convenient, I've had a decent amount of software throw weird errors when I use symlinks, so I avoid them when it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can set the `layout` or `type` field to `posts` in the frontmatter of your `_index.md` file in `content/blog1`.</strike>

See [this docs page](https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/) for more info.

Edit: Alternatively, you could create an archetype for `blog1` that automatically sets the value to `posts` in the frontmatter of individual posts in that section, assuming you're using `hugo new blog1/postname.md` to create posts for that section.

Double edit: The first suggestion didn't work. You could also create subsections within `content/posts/blog1` and set the permalinks of posts in that subsection to use the last section only. That should remove the need to explicitly set the type in post frontmatter every time because each post would already have a type of posts.

In `config.toml`:

```
[permalinks]
    posts = "/:sections[last]/:slug/"
```

Comment: Am I doing it wrong? When I do `layout = "posts"` or `type = "posts"`, it sets the index page *itself* to be a blog post, and all the sub-pages are still pages of type "myblog1". I'd rather not have to explicitly set the layout on each page in "myblog1", even if it is set by a template.

Comment: Hmm, I could've sworn that was possible..maybe not. You could also create subsections within `content/posts/blog1` and set the permalinks of posts in that subsection to use the last section only. This is what I do in my blog. That should remove the need to explicitly set the type in post frontmatter every time because each post would already have a type of posts. The only downside to this (that I haven't found a suitable solution for) is that list pages only will still contain `posts` in the permalink. Only singles will omit it. I'll update the post with the permalink config.

Comment: This works for me. @Paul, Have you created a new archetype for "blog" or whatever you're calling it? That may be the missing piece here. Then setting the "type: blog" in the content frontmatter should apply the template from layouts/blog/single.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partial in your templates. If you do that you WILL need the single and list file in the layouts/blog directory, but it could be an empty file referencing the partial. The layouts/posts/single.html and the layouts/blog/single.html both will then look like this:

```
{{ partial "singleblog.html" . }}
```

Compeletely DRY... and without much complexity.